# How to find out currently using display device from DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync results for Projection

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp, projection

I am trying to find out the display which the user is currently using as primary display for the computer/laptop, so that I can show the available displays to the user, which supports projection and can be used using `ProjectionManager` [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.projectionmanager). Please remember that, this is for UWP application.

```
    DeviceInformationCollection displayDevices = DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(ProjectionManager.GetDeviceSelector());
```

`DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(...)` returns a collection of `DeviceInformation`. `DeviceInformation` has `Pairing` property, but that always returns false (Even for Primary Display).

Is there any other APIs which I can use to get the primary display/currently using display?

For example:

1. The `DeviceId` I get from `DeviceInformation` can be used `BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(String DeviceId)` for Bluetooth specific API requirements, such as - `Connected` status.
2. Can I get the currently using display id `DeviceId` and match with `DeviceInformation.DeviceId` from the collection to discard it?

Is something like that available for `ProjectionManager`? I have gone through [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.projectionmanager), also [github examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/Projection) and couldn't find anything suitable. So, help needed. Thanks.

Comment: `Pairing` tells you if a device is paired (connected) over Bluetooth/WiFi or not. It has nothing to do with the primary display.  It will tell you if a wireless mouse, printer or projector is paired

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. That's just an observation I mentioned. But that's not the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any other APIs which I can use to get the primary display/currently using display?

`ProjectionManager` has no such api could detect primary display or not. but you could use `DisplayRegion` to detect it.

if you want to get primary, you could check if current DisplayRegion `WorkAreaOffset` is `{0,0}`. and it has device id property, you could use it to get matched monitor.

```
IReadOnlyList<DisplayRegion> displayRegions = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().WindowingEnvironment.GetDisplayRegions();
   
// count all the DisplayRegions that are marked as available to the app for use.
foreach (DisplayRegion displayregion in displayRegions)
{
    if (displayregion.IsVisible)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(displayregion.WorkAreaOffset);

    }
}
```

For getting currently using display.

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().GetDisplayRegions()[0]
```

For more code  please refer to official [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/AppWindow).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and official code reference. Will check soon and let you know my feedback.